# Looking to create a tap and hold button to generate more buttons

Tags: ios, button, tapandhold

So if any of you have used the tumblr mobile app recently, you'll notice that the reblog function has a tap and hold capability. Essentially when you tap and hold the reblog button, more buttons pop up around it so the user can just drag their finger over one of the new buttons and release to select it. I've been digging around and no one seems to have an answer to this specific question.I've always seen this as a very elegant way to have a sub menu and would like to implement it into my own apps. For ios btw.

Answer (score 0):

Add gesture recognizer to a view. write a method to create buttons when long press gesture is done on the view.